# Regular Expression for String representing DNA code

Tags: regex

Hello
I am trying to use regular expressions in a java program. I would like the regex to identify a String of unknown length and whose charachters are only 'C', 'A', 'G' or  'T'.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy, just use a character class:

```
[CAGT]+
```

Or if the entire string has to comprise of the chars CAGT for it to match:

```
^[CAGT]+$
```

Comment: The entire String has to be made up of only 'C', 'A', 'T' or 'G'

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above :

```
^[CAGTcagt]+$
```

To ensure detection of lowercase and upper case charcters.

Comment: wouldn't the /i flag take care of this?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the most voted answer. With `[ACGT]+`, a large string will lead to a lot of memory usage. So I would use a negated regex instead, and check if the string doesn't contain non [ACGT] characters instead:

```
str !~ [^ACGTacgt]
```