# Regular expression matching the DNA sequence of a viable life form

Tags: regex, lifecycle, dna-sequence

I'm looking for a regular expression matching the DNA sequence of a viable life form.

I'm not very particular about the definition of "viable life form", as long as it's able to hatch out of an egg and survive for a couple of minutes, I'm fine with that.

But still, I expect something more specific than these answers [Regular Expression for String representing DNA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019350/regular-expression-for-string-representing-dna-code)

Comment: If you want more specific care to describe why those answers are LESS specific!

Comment: Well, `^[CAGT]+$` matches any random DNA sequence of any length, that might result in life-forms that are not viable _at all_.

Comment: Can you give a rule when DNA is correct?

Comment: That is the point of my question. there must be a simple pattern common to most life-forms.

Comment: This is a programming site, not a biological. Go here http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I found some clues here, but only for proteins: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42038/rna-to-protein-translation

Answer (score 0):

For Procaryota you may use "AGGAGG". That is the Shine-Dalgamo sequence essence for survival of bacteria.
For Eucaryota maybe TATAAA (TATA box) helps.